# vim-powerline does not have the correct appearance

Tags: vim, vim-powerline

I installed it with Vundle and my .vimrc look contains the following

```
" Powerline setup
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ for\ Powerline\ 9
set laststatus=2
```

I am using the default Gnome Terminal than comes with Ubuntu 14.04. I don't know if it installed correctly (I followed this [Vim as Python IDE](http://unlogic.co.uk/2013/02/08/vim-as-a-python-ide/#powerline) tutorial) but it does not look anything like the screenshots.

Here is what is it meant to look like: [Official Screenshots](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#vim-statusline)

[image: official screenshot]

And here is what it actually looks like:

[image: my screenshot]

As you can see, zero similarity.

Comment: You are wasting your time. Read `:h 'statusline'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'guifont'` option applies only to GVIM. In the terminal, Vim uses the default terminal font. So, you need to go to Gnome Terminal's settings (*Edit > Profile Preferences > /General\ > Font:*) and change the font there, too (assuming Powerline supports the terminal at all, which I don't know).

Also, check how many colors Vim detects via `:set t_Co?`; you can influence / correct that by defining the correct `$TERM` value, probably `gnome-256color` for your.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the patched fonts?

https://github.com/powerline/fonts